# Using multiprocessing across Python versions

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I was wondering if I can use multiprocessing to run Python 2.7 code from within Python 3.7, since it spawns a new interpreter anyway. The following code (`try_multiproc.py`) seems to run fine under any Python 2.7 interpreter:

```
import multiprocessing

def foo():
    print('foo')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ipath = r"C:\miniconda3\envs\py2env\python.exe"  # path to Python 2.7 interpreter in a conda env
    multiprocessing.set_executable(ipath)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
```

However when I try to run it under a Python 3.7 interpreter, I get:

```
$ python try_multiproc.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named spawn
```

Am I trying to do something that's fundamentally impossible, or is this due to some issues with my conda environment? (However as noted above, it seems to work fine across 2.7 environments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came across the same problem and did some digging, sadly it doesn't appear to be possible to do.

[`multiprocessing.spawn.get_command_line`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L86) sets up the code for the executable to run. It'll look something like this:

```
["python2.exe" "-c" "from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(parent_pid=16524, pipe_handle=496)" "--multiprocessing-fork"]
```

Since `multiprocessing.spawn` was renamed from `multiprocessing.forking`, the above line won't be understood by Python 2. I attempted creating a dummy `spawn.py` file, where `spawn_main` calls `forking.main`, but I then started getting bad file descriptor errors, and as the class is incredibly complex, it's not worth the effort to debug.

Getting this working was extremely difficult. I ended up using `subprocessing` to spawn the other python process, and I had to pass in the module import path and function name to execute. Dealing with `stderr` is a pain, since not every "error" is an exception, so it needed a bit of hacky code to detect if it needs to re-raise or ignore the error. Finally, I had to print out the base64 encoded result from the subprocess, grab and decode this from `stdout`, and print everything else.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Looks complicated indeed.